# Is there a requests function that allows to extract only a portion of a JSON response from an api?

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I have this giant response and I just need the IDs in "SingleItemOffers" at the end of the response (I had to cut down a lot of the json reponse due to stack overflow):

```
{
    "FeaturedBundle": {
        "Bundle": {
            "ID": "2b18d53c-6173-460e-bb72-63bbb114b182",
            "DataAssetID": "441117e1-40be-42e2-3aeb-49957e5c03fd",
            "CurrencyID": "85ad13f7-3d1b-5128-9eb2-7cd8ee0b5741",
            "Items": [
                {
                    "Item": {
                        "ItemTypeID": "e7c63390-eda7-46e0-bb7a-a6abdacd2433",
                        "ItemID": "291cb44a-410d-b035-4d0b-608a92c2cd91",
                        "Amount": 1
                    },
                    "BasePrice": 1775,
                    "CurrencyID": "85ad13f7-3d1b-5128-9eb2-7cd8ee0b5741",
                    "DiscountPercent": 0.33,
                    "DiscountedPrice": 1189,
                    "IsPromoItem": false
                }
            ]
        },
        "BundleRemainingDurationInSeconds": 804392
    },
    "SkinsPanelLayout": {
        "SingleItemOffers": [
            "5a0cd3b5-4249-bf6f-d009-17a81532660e",
            "7e44fc1b-44fa-cdda-8491-f8a5bca1cfa3",
            "daa73753-4b56-9d21-d73e-f3b3f4c9b1a6",
            "f7425a39-43ca-e1fe-5b2b-56a51ed479c5"
        ],
        "SingleItemOffersRemainingDurationInSeconds": 37592
    }
}
```

This is my code at the moment and when I print the reponse it prints the entire thing:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://pd.na.a.pvp.net/store/v2/storefront/XXX"

payload={}
headers = {
  'X-Riot-Entitlements-JWT': 'XXX',
  'Authorization': 'XXX'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: I'd just parse the payload using the `json` module, then access the parsed response dictionary like any other dictionary.

Comment: There may be a parameter of the api which selects less information, but otherwise did you mean: `response.json()["SkinsPanelLayout"]["SingleItemOffers"]`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

response[0]["FeaturedBundle"]["Bundle"]["ID"]

you can use it specifically with a FOR loop to change the sub index and get a longer response, I hope it helps you, greetings.